# A* (a-star) issues finding shortest path - specific example

Tags: path-finding, a-star

[image: A* Issue]

In this example (please see picture), the Manhattan heuristic delays the path because of the unwalkable block west of the destination block.

My question is how can I fix this? Do I need to keep checking the blocks on the open list (the gray blocks) even after I found the destination? I might as well use dijkstra if I have to do that. Do I have to live with an imperfection like this if I go with a-star or is there a solution?

I have done my research on it and implemented my own algorithm that works exactly as the tutorials / articles on the web have explained, but I keep running into specific instances like this where a* fails to find the shortest path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heuristic needs to be [admissible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) but is not.  Use [Diagonal or Euclidean distance](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html#heuristics-for-grid-maps) instead.

Comment: Diagonal causes various other, more severe problems in certain cases. I'll post an example of it but first I'll see if how Euclidean fares. I never tried Euclidean before fearing worse performance. I have no other choice at this point.

Comment: @NathanielG.M. The performance difference should be negligible, but there shouldn't be anything wrong with Diagonal heuristic.  If there is, there is something wrong with your implementation.

Comment: There are a few cases with diagonal where the lowest f cost goes the opposite direction from the destination, going through way too many nodes before it can find the destination. Especially in maps with many corridors, it often reaches dead ends and has to look through the open list to find alternative paths. It finds the shortest paths eventually but it always seemed to me like it should not take that much searching. Upon further testing I see that you are right, performance is quite fine with euclidean. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @NathanielG.M. That sounds like you calculated the heuristic incorrectly, maybe you screwed up the sign of some variable.  The algorithm shouldn't ever _start out_ moving away from the goal, if it's able to move towards it.